# How to estimate the bandwidth/throughput of grpc

Tags: c++, network-programming, grpc, bandwidth, estimation

I am working on a network related project, where communication between client and server is implemented by **grpc-cpp**. I want to estimate the bandwidth/throughput of data transfer between server and client. Currently, client sends request containing data and server will reply a short message. The data is transferred as `bytes` with size 10~100KB.

It can be easy to estimate the bandwidth on client side by measuring the time difference between sending and receiving, then minus the execution time on server. But how to do that on server side? It looks like the `GlobalCallbacks::PreSynchronousRequest` is called only after the whole frame has been received, and there is no way to know the duration between two packets (each contains a part of the whole frame).

Is there any other way to roughly estimate the bandwidth between server-client on server side?

Comment: How do you estimate bandwidth with time? Are you sending a non-trivial sized payload? If it's a tiny amount, like under 1KB, you'll end up measuring latency instead.

Comment: @tadman the size of data is likely to be 10~100KB. Sorry for the confusion, the word "bandwidth" here indicates a general concept, you can also understand it as "throughput", which is the amount of data transferred divided by corresponding duration.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to achieve with this bandwidth measurement, tools can vary but I suggest to start with a network throughput measuring tool such as `iptraf`, `iftop`, so on. Then you don't need to implement this by yourself with the limitation of gRPC API which isn't meant to measure this bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what I want is to have a real-time in program bandwidth measurement and do workload scheduling based on that. Thus, such kind of console-based tools may not work for me.